# Forcing ttl's in varnish 6.2

Tags: varnish-vcl

I've been looking at the latest version of Varnish (6.2) and having problems with the removal of return(miss) from vcl_hit.

So our use case is that we want to cache things for a set amount of time, then force varnish to retrieve new content, in previous versions the following has worked fine

```
sub vcl_hit {

        if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
            return (deliver);
        }
        else
        {
            return (miss);
        }
    }
```

However in 6.2 return(miss) has been removed, we want to force content to always be refreshed correctly.

I looked at return(pass) but from the documentation this suggests that the response will not be cached, which is not what we want.

and return(fetch) has not been an option for some time, but I'm struggling to find an alternative?  As return(restart) suggested in the docs will just loop back to the same place.

Should I be looking elsewhere, and trying to disable grace/saint?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Now in varnish 6.3 > we can't event do `return (miss);`

Comment: @Kash we went with 'return (pass)' in the end as while the documentation reads like it won't cache, it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

`vcl_hit` is the wrong subroutine for a handful of reasons, the main one you are using a complicated way, with side-effects, to do something trivial. Just do:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    # set the ttl
    set beresp.ttl = 5m;
    # after ttl is gone, grace kicks in during which
    # content is revalidated asynchronously
    set beresp.grace = 2h;
    # after grace, keep kicks during which
    # content is revalidated synchronously
    set beresp.keep = 3d;
}
```

Your snippet is equivalent to setting grace and keep to `0s`.

Comment: I think you're missing what I was asking, I want grace and keep to be 0s so that content is refreshed on time when it expires.

Comment: so just set grace and keep to 0s and it will do what you ask, no need to touch vcl_hit.

Unless you want varnish to automatically trigger a fetch at the end of TTL, which isn't possible (never has been), we need a client request for that.